# Otimizar codigo Java

Tags: java, android, otimização, switch

Boas, estou a criar um alarme em android e queria saber se inves de ter de fazer um switch para cada editText se avia forma de verificar todos em um só switch, tentei com um for e fui incrementado, mas sem sucesso, aqui esta o meu codigo, espero que me possam ajudar.
PS: Tambem aceito dicas para otimizar o meu codigo.

```
private EditText edit1, edit2, edit3;
private Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
    edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    edit2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit2);
    edit3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit3);
    verificarEdits();
}
void verificarEdits(){
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            edit1();
        }
        void edit1() {
            switch (edit1.getText().length()) {
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(activity2.this, "Falta preencher a mensagem que deseja no alarme", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    edit2();
            }
        }
        void edit2(){
            switch (edit2.getText().length()) {
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(activity2.this, "Falta preencher as horas para que deseja o alarme.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    edit3();
            }
        }
        void edit3() {
            switch (edit3.getText().length()) {
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(activity2.this, "Falta preencher os minutos para que deseja o alarme.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    converterValores();
            }
        }
    });
}
void converterValores() {
    String mensagem = (edit1.getText().toString());
    int horas = Integer.parseInt(edit2.getText().toString());
    int minutos = Integer.parseInt(edit3.getText().toString());
    enviarValores(mensagem, horas, minutos);
}
void enviarValores(String message, int hour, int minutes) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM)
            .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
            .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour)
            .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minutes);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer os testes todos seguidos com `ifs` que ficam bem curtos e legíveis. Apenas necessita de testar diretamente o `length` de cada um dos `EditText` e criar a mensagem de erro caso seja `0`:

```
void verificarEdits(){
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String erro = "";

            if (edit1.getText().length() == 0){
                erro += "Falta preencher a mensagem que deseja no alarme\n";
            }
            if (edit2.getText().length() == 0){
                erro += "Falta preencher as horas para que deseja o alarme.\n";
            }
            if (edit3.getText().length() == 0){
                erro += "Falta preencher os minutos para que deseja o alarme.\n";
            }

            if (erro.equals("")){ //se não apanhou erro até aqui converte
                converterValores();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(activity2.this, erro, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }         
        }
    });
}
```

Assim como está aparecem as mensagens para cada campo que está vazio. Se tiver os 3 vazios aparece o *Toast* com 3 mensagens de erro. Se preferir que apenas apareça uma de cada vez da primeira para a ultima apenas precisa de trocar os `if` do `edit2` e `edit3` para `else if`.

Uma vez que está a converter o texto escrito pelo usuário para inteiro, pode falhar se tiver letras ou outros símbolos e por isso é aconselhável que capture a exceção que representa essa falha:

```
void converterValores() {
    String mensagem = (edit1.getText().toString());

    try {
        int horas = Integer.parseInt(edit2.getText().toString());
        int minutos = Integer.parseInt(edit3.getText().toString());
        enviarValores(mensagem, horas, minutos);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
        Toast.makeText(this,"As horas e os minutos tem de ser valores númericos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Existem algumas maneiras de otimizar o seu código:

Em vez de usar vários métodos aninhados para verificar cada um dos EditTexts, você pode colocar todas as verificações em um único método. Isso pode deixar o código mais legível e fácil de entender. Por exemplo:

```
void verificarEdits(){
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (edit1.getText().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(activity2.this, "Falta preencher a mensagem que deseja no alarme", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (edit2.getText().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(activity2.this, "Falta preencher as horas para que deseja o alarme.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (edit3.getText().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(activity2.this, "Falta preencher os minutos para que deseja o alarme.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            converterValores();
        }
    });
}
```

Em vez de criar um método separado para converter os valores dos EditTexts em strings e inteiros, você pode fazer isso diretamente no método enviarValores. Isso pode deixar o código mais simples e evitar a criação de mais um método. Por exemplo:

```
void enviarValores() {
    String mensagem = edit1.getText().toString();
    int horas = Integer.parseInt(edit2.getText().toString());
    int minutos = Integer.parseInt(edit3.getText().toString());

    Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM)
            .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, mensagem)
            .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, horas)
            .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minutos);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Em vez de usar a função switch para verificar o comprimento de cada um dos EditTexts, você pode usar uma condição if simples. Isso pode deixar o código mais legível e fácil de entender. Por exemplo:

```
void verificarEdits(){
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (edit1.getText().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(activity2.this, "Falta preencher a mensagem que deseja no alarme", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (edit2.getText().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(activity2.this, "Falta preencher as horas para que deseja o alarme.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (edit3.getText().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(activity2.this, "Falta preencher os minutos para que deseja o alarme.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            converterValores();
        }
    });
}
```